# mysql get mixed result from 2 queries on same table with different order

Tags: php, mysql

thanks for dedicating time.

I have two tables for a kind of social network, table A for contents and table B for likes:

TABLE A:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` text,
  `ext` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link_url` text,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `number_share` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `A`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `id_user` (`id_user`);
```

And TABLE B:

```
CREATE TABLE B (
  `id_b` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `B`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_b`,`id_user`), ADD KEY `id_user` (`id_user`);
```

I'd like to retrieve from mysql records with this order:

```
    1st most popular 
     1st most recent
     2nd most popular 
     2nd most recent



    .....
```

Can anyone tell me how to combine this by mysql (if possibile) or something easy to use in php wich is not 2 different queries?

**EDIT 1:**

If i have this situation:

results from first select (popular): 
id 
3 
5 
12 
4 
65 
2

and

results from second select (recent):

```
id 
100 
121 
3
```

i will go to print my elements width id:

```
id
3 
100 
5 
121 
12
```

i want that id=3 from the second query is not considered because already posted

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are right, i update echo.

Comment: How do you define 'popular' content?

Comment: That one that has max number of records in B table  with join condition on A.id = B.id_b

Comment: a or atm_moodboard. Please decide. And where's atm_users

Comment: Was just late night when i updated and dismissed that. Thanks for -1 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plan**

> - use variable, and order by to rank popularity
> - use variable, and order by to rank recent
> - union all
> - re order by rnk, cat
> - group by id to restrict to first id

**input [sample]**

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+------------+----------+--------------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
| id | id_user | title  |  path  |  ext   | image_type | link_url |      creation_date       |  size  |  type  | number_share |
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+------------+----------+--------------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |      22 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null)     | (null)   | August, 09 2015 10:54:57 | (null) | (null) |            0 |
|  2 |      33 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null)     | (null)   | August, 09 2015 07:54:57 | (null) | (null) |            0 |
|  3 |      44 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null)     | (null)   | August, 09 2015 08:54:57 | (null) | (null) |            0 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+------------+----------+--------------------------+--------+--------+--------------+

+------+---------+
| id_b | id_user |
+------+---------+
|    3 |       8 |
|    3 |       9 |
|    3 |      21 |
|    3 |      22 |
|    1 |      55 |
|    3 |      55 |
|    1 |      66 |
|    1 |      77 |
+------+---------+
```

**query**

```
set @rnk_pop := 0;
set @rnk_rec := 0;

-- popularity ranking
select cat, id, rnk
from
(
select cat, id, rnk
from
(
  select cat, id, occurs, @rnk_pop := @rnk_pop + 1 as rnk
  from
  (
    select 'popularity' as cat, A.id, count(B.id_b) as occurs
    from A
    left join B
    on B.id_b = A.id
    group by A.id
    order by occurs desc
  ) q1
) pop_sort
union all
-- recent ranking
select cat, id, rnk
from
(
  select 'recent' as cat, id, @rnk_rec := @rnk_rec + 1 as rnk
  from A
  order by creation_date desc
) rec_sort
order by rnk, cat
) all_q
group by id
order by rnk, cat
;
```

**output**

```
+------------+----+-----+
|    cat     | id | rnk |
+------------+----+-----+
| popularity |  3 |   1 |
| recent     |  1 |   1 |
| popularity |  2 |   3 |
+------------+----+-----+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d02808/17)

**notes**

ranking output above would be used to join to display whatever information is useful about the content..

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to update your fiddle setting insert into B
 ( id_b, id_user )
 values
 ( 1, 55 ),
 ( 1, 66 ),
 ( 1, 77 ),
 ( 3, 55 ),
 ( 3, 8 ),
 ( 3, 9 ),
 ( 3, 22 ),
 ( 3, 21 )
 ;  

as values. I expected that id = 3 would be the first of popular list but it does not work. Can you explain if i'm doing wrong please? thanks!

Comment: note the issue seems to be that the group by and aggregate results need to be computed first before i select using the variable with order over the aggregate `occurs`. ive updated the code ( and fiddle ) to address this issue

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you! The only thing to solve is avoid getting duplicated id. i tried putting DISTINCT in main select but dows not work. Thank you man!

Comment: Being from the same table i don't wanna show twice the same record. If i get id=3 twice i have to show just first time. I can do saving an array of id's in php but i think i can add distinct clause in the union result?

Comment: I would like to display first id=3 that i find. I don't wanna duplicated id in sql result. for examples (not working) select distinct id from ((1st select) union (2nd select)) or something like that. So i just get id=3 once in the better position. Hope it's clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86588/discussion-between-amdixon-and-sbo).